# Sublime Text Theme: Change the background of the search bar

Tags: themes, customization, sublimetext, flat

I've been editing my own theme for Sublime Text, but I got stuck at one bit.

I couldn't find a way to modify the color of the Input field of the **search bar**. I've managed to apply a background image to the container of the input (as you can see in the image bellow with a border), but I couldn't remove the white background of the input.

[image: White Input field]

I know that it got be a way to remove, because the Soda themes have different colors there. The question is: how?

And also, is it possible to change the font color of this input?

Thank you!
Lucas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, all example codes here are from [Soda Theme](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme). It is a wonderful theme.

You can create a custom color scheme and use it. It seems that this may affect all widgets, such as output, side bar and the input fields. **And you need to restart Sublime Text to make it take affect.**

Take [Widget - Soda Dark.stTheme](https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/blob/master/Soda%20Dark/Widget%20-%20Soda%20Dark.stTheme) for example: change `background` value.

```
<string>Soda Dark - Widget Theme</string>
<key>settings</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#383838</string>
            <key>caret</key>
            <string>#F8F8F8</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#F8F8F8</string>
            <key>invisibles</key>
            <string>#3B3B3B</string>
```

Use it as color scheme:

```
{
  "color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Soda/Soda Dark/Widget - Soda Dark.stTheme",
  "draw_shadows": false
}
```

Besides, you can custom the text input fields in your theme via `text_line_control`.

```
// Text input field item
{
    "class": "text_line_control",
    "layer0.texture": "Theme - Soda/Soda Dark/text-field.png",
    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "layer0.inner_margin": [4, 5, 4, 3],
    "content_margin": [3, 3]
},
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I've tried this before, but I haven't realised that I had to restart Sublime in order to apply the changes form the .stTheme.
I also found a related issue at their Github account: https://github.com/buymeasoda/soda-theme/issues/128

Comment: @LucasMotta You are right. Restart Sublime Text is a must. I've updated the answer.

Comment: !!Important - Remember to remove the theme in Cache folder.