# How to custome Sublime Text 3 UI Theme bottom text field/search bar font size

Tags: themes, sublimetext3

I've been customizing an existing UI theme and was able to modify sidebar, status bar, scrollbars, and bottom panel except the font size of the search bar and its background color. I would like to make it bigger.

Would you know where I can find it in e.g mycustomtheme.sublime-theme... or maybe it's located in some other file?

Thanks for your help :)

[image: sublime text 3 bottom search field]

Comment: The panel can be [resized vertically by dragging it with the mouse](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30847336/3870761). The font-size usually can be changed using ctrl+mouse-wheel. You can see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544176/sublime-text-theme-change-the-background-of-the-search-bar) and answer for help on how to change the colour.

Comment: @sergioFC thanks, yep I can change the height of the bottom panel, but the font size stays the same haha... I guess I just have to fork other themes with big find/replace font size already and redo customization which would be much easier... I had another go today with fresh eyes... but still can't find how to do it... sooooo, abandon ship... :)  :)